# Neo4j: how can i save data into neo4j image?

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am using Neo4j docker image and created container. Then added some data into container.

Now I want to export container as image for future usage **with data** included inside docker image.

`How can I do it?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A docker container can be commited into an image using the command `docker commit <container-name> <target-image-name>`.

**HOWEVER**, as described in the docker [commit command docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description):

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.

The [neo4j image](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j-publish/blob/9a175bdb484967c609c5c369256b866a577f86b3/3.3.1/community/Dockerfile) declares `/data` as a volume, thus the commit command won't include the data that you have created which is stored under `/data` inside the container.
You need to maually copy this folder and copy it back into the new container.

```
docker cp <old-container-name>:/data container-data
docker run -v container-data:/data <commited-image>
```

**Update**:

If you want to put the data inside the commited image then create a custom image as such:

```
FROM <commited-image>
COPY container-data /data
```

Once you build this image using `docker build` you should get an identical image to the running container. You can then push this image to a
docker registry and run it on anther host.

Comment: I wanted to prepare docker image with data to run it in another host without adding data again. Can I make it shipped with neo4j data already?

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov Updated answer. However, you need to extract the data folder from the container. There is no other way around.

Answer (score 0):

1)you need to use docker build command in order to first build image
i.e docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
2) use Docker push command to push that image into your repository hub
docker push [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG]

and after that you can download via docker pull  to use that image

Answer (score 0):

The command `docker commit` is designed for this.

See the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

For example, if

`docker ps`

shows my container with the id

123abc456def

and the name

neo4j

I can do either

`docker commit 123abc456def  myuser/myimage:myversion`

or

`docker commit neo4j  myuser/myimage:myversion`

and so

`docker images`

will now show my commited image